# How to use mobs to make players "turn into" those mobs, but teleport the mob somewhere else if they change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Alright so for a pvp map, im making a **Druid** class and they're gonna use *polar bears* and *ocelots* with custom names for **"forms"**. I was wondering if I could make it so that I could teleport the polar bear to them if they hold an **item**, but if they **let go**, then the polar bear is moved away off of them.

Comment: So basically turn the player invisible and move the mob if something in in the holding slot?

Comment: Without mods, I'm not sure this is possible. You could use a command to turn the player invisible, then "mount" the animal when you summon it, but some creatures aren't able to be mounted, so they won't be able to control the animal

Comment: No need to mount the animal, just teleport it to the player's position constantly. This should be fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned, There is no way to do so in vanilla minecraft, but to make the player turn into a mob, you could either do one of two things:

- Make the player invisible and then summon the mob being "mounted"
- Or to start a command chain to teleport the mob to the players coordinates constanly